# Laravel | Save and display two relations

Tags: laravel, pivot-table, relationship

I'm close to finish my CMS but I have one minor problem.

I can create several teams, works perfectly fine.

I can create several games, works also perfectly fine.

Now I want to create matches between those teams, which means I have two pivot tables.
One called `game_match` and the other called `match_team`.

`game_match` consist of `game_id`and `match_id`

`match_team`consist of `match_id`, `team1_id`and `team2_id`

My `match/create.blade.php` has two dropdown fields for each team.

Saving a single relation to the database works fine for me as I've done this a couple of times, but I can't figure out how to save two relations.

This is what I got so far:

Inside `match/create.blade.php`

```
<div class="field m-t-20 is-inline-block">
    <p class="control">
        <label for="home" class="label"><b>{{ trans_choice('messages.home', 1) }}</b></label>
        <input type="hidden" name="home" id="home" :value="homeSelected">
        <div class="select">
            <select v-model="homeSelected">
                @foreach($teams as $team)
                    <option value="{{ $team->id }}">{{ $team->name }}</option>
                @endforeach
            </select>
        </div>
    </p>
</div>

<div class="field m-t-20 is-inline-block">
    <p class="control">
        <label for="opponent" class="label"><b>{{ trans_choice('messages.opponent', 1) }}</b></label>
        <input type="hidden" name="opponent" id="opponent" :value="opponentSelected">
        <div class="select">
            <select v-model="opponentSelected">
                @foreach($teams as $team)
                    <option value="{{ $team->id }}">{{ $team->name }}</option>
                @endforeach
            </select>
        </div>
    </p>
</div>

@section('scripts')
    <script>
        var app = new Vue({
            el: '#app',
            data: {
                homeSelected: "",
                opponentSelected: "",
                gameSelected: ""
            }
        });
    </script>
@endsection
```

`MatchController.php`

```
public function store(Request $request)
    {
        $this->validate($request, [
            'title' => 'required|max:255',
            'matchday' => 'required',
        ]);

        $match = new Match();

        $match->title = $request->title;
        $match->matchday = $request->matchday;

        if ($match->save()) {
            $match->games()->sync($request->game);
            $match->teams()->sync( [
                ['team1_id' => $request->home, 'team2_id' => $request->opponent],
            ]);

            Session::flash('success', trans('messages.created', ['item' => $match->title]));
            return redirect()->route('matches.show', $match->id);
        } else {
            Session::flash('error', trans('messages.error'));
            return redirect()->route('matches.create')->withInput();
        }
    }
```

`match.php`

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\SoftDeletes;

class Match extends Model
{
    use SoftDeletes; // <-- Use This Instead Of SoftDeletingTrait

    protected $fillable = [
        'title'
    ];

    protected $dates = ['deleted_at'];

    public function setHomeTeam () {}

    public function teams () {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Team', 'match_team', 'match_id', 'team1_id');
    }

    public function games () {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Game', 'game_match');
    }

    public function getHomeTeam() {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Team', 'match_team', 'match_id', 'team1_id');
    }

    public function getOpponentTeam() {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Team', 'match_team', 'match_id', 'team2_id');
    }
}
```

Can someone help me?

Answer (score 0):

You should better use firstOrCreate(), updateOrCreate or attach() methods.

Comment: That doesn't solve the problem I'm facing with saving two relations of the same foreign table.